# Show/hide menu not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created DropDown menu with jQuery. Everything works great except IE7. Not working at all. It only makes bold the last link. I'm not sure how to debug it.

I created [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EMnw3/1/)

Does anyone have a solution?

This is JS that doesn't work:

```
 $(".link-dropdown").on({
        click: function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.parent().next().is(":visible")){
                $('.opening-holder').hide();
                $('.link-dropdown').css({
                    'fontFamily': 'Geogrotesque-Regular, Arial, sans-serif'
                });
            } else {
                $('.opening-holder').hide();
                $('.link-dropdown').css({
                    'fontFamily': 'Geogrotesque-Regular, Arial, sans-serif'
                });

                $this.css({
                    'fontFamily': 'Geogrotesque-SemiBold, Arial, sans-serif'
                });

                $this.parent().next().show();
                $this.parent().next().children().show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post you relevant code here and add a decent problem description please. "Not working at all" isn't an **error message** nor a **problem description**.

Comment: I added some more info. I created fiddle with example

Comment: This is the solution
http://jsfiddle.net/EMnw3/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created fiddle for solution http://jsfiddle.net/EMnw3/27/
I disabled if visible and it works...

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the fact you have used `:visible`.

Comment: I put $this.parent().next().is(":not(:hidden)") instead of 
if ($this.parent().next().is(":visible"))
and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

I have just made changes to jQuery scripting and it is working as below:

```
$(function(){
    $(".link-dropdown").on({
        click: function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.css("dispaly") == "block;"){
                $('.opening-holder').hide();
                $('.link-dropdown').css({
                    'fontFamily': 'Geogrotesque-Regular, Arial, sans-serif'
                });
            } else {
                $('.opening-holder').hide();
                $('.link-dropdown').css({
                    'fontFamily': 'Geogrotesque-Regular, Arial, sans-serif'
                });

                $this.css({
                    'fontFamily': 'Geogrotesque-SemiBold, Arial, sans-serif'
                });

                $this.parent().show();
                $this.parent().children().show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```